# Vi replace the currently searched string

Tags: vim

I know how I can search and replace a string, either globally or in a selected area.

But I have the habit to go over a word and then hit `*` to search for that word. This won't only search for the word string, but it will also ignore other strings of which the searched string is a sub string. So the search looks like `\<word\>` instead of just `word`.

Now I'd like to be able to hit `*` on a word, and then replace all of the already searched and highlighted occurrences of that string, without having to enter it again for the search & replace command. Is there a good way of doing that?

Comment: Typing `:s/` and then control+r and then `/` appears to pull in what `*` searched for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sample text:

```
cat
concatenate
scat
dog and cat
```

Say `*` is pressed on first line, it will search for pattern `\<cat\>`

When search string is left empty during search and replace, it will reuse the last matched pattern, So doing

```
:%s//CAT/g
```

will result in

```
CAT
concatenate
scat
dog and CAT
```

From `:h :substitute`

> If the {pattern} for the substitute command is empty, the command uses
>   the pattern from the last substitute or `:global` command.  If there
>   is none, but there is a previous search pattern, that one is used. 
>   With the [r] flag, the command uses the pattern from the last
>   substitute, `:global`, or search command.

To change behavior of `*` and `#` for visually selected text to search only part of text instead of whole word:

```
vnoremap * y/<C-R>"<CR>
vnoremap # y?<C-R>"<CR>
```

Comment: See `g*` or `g#` to _search only part of text_

Answer (score 3):

You could use `g*` instead of `*`. From [`:help gstar`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#gstar)

```
g*          Like "*", but don't put "\<" and "\>" around the word.
            This makes the search also find matches that are not a
            whole word.  {not in Vi}

g#          Like "#", but don't put "\<" and "\>" around the word.
            This makes the search also find matches that are not a
            whole word.  {not in Vi}
```

And then use:

```
:%s//replacement/g
```

as @Sundeep suggested.